# Reading multiple XMLs in Python: ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing

I have to read nearly a thousand XML files and perform clustering on the X- and Y-coordinates in them. To do so, I open each of them, run a few loops to get the coordinates and append them to a dataframe. However, I get the common error below. Having gone through the other solutions for this issue, I’m afraid changing the encoding to UTF-8 does nothing to solve the problem.

```
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1
```

One of the XML files looks as follows. The Coordinates tags are found within the CrossMark tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KinoveaVideoAnalysis>
  <FormatVersion>2.0</FormatVersion>
  <Producer>Kinovea.0.8.27</Producer>
  <OriginalFilename>Pagulayan vs Yapp (Last 16) 2019 US Open 9-ball 18</OriginalFilename>
  <FullPath>D:\Online Learning Courses\Kinovea Analysis\Pagulayan vs Yapp (Last 16) 2019 US Open 9-ball 18.jpg</FullPath>
  <ImageSize>1920;1080</ImageSize>
  <AverageTimeStampsPerFrame>1</AverageTimeStampsPerFrame>
  <CaptureFramerate>25</CaptureFramerate>
  <UserFramerate>25</UserFramerate>
  <FirstTimeStamp>0</FirstTimeStamp>
  <SelectionStart>1</SelectionStart>
  <Calibration>
    <CalibrationLine>
      <Origin>960;540</Origin>
      <Scale>1</Scale>
    </CalibrationLine>
    <Unit Abbreviation="px">Pixels</Unit>
  </Calibration>
  <Keyframes>
    <Keyframe id="d9c9e54a-66d8-4eed-82cc-d1bdb5c97eeb">
      <Position UserTime="0:00:00:00">1</Position>
      <Title>0:00:00:00</Title>
      <Drawings>
        <Plane id="a5ea55a7-3aca-4986-8fb3-386be2de5118" name="Perspective grid 1">
          <PointUpperLeft>279.8182;166.9091</PointUpperLeft>
          <PointUpperRight>1651.909;166.9091</PointUpperRight>
          <PointLowerRight>1651.909;871.3636</PointLowerRight>
          <PointLowerLeft>279.8182;871.3636</PointLowerLeft>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="color">
              <Value>255;100;149;237</Value>
            </Color>
            <GridDivisions Key="divisions">
              <Value>8</Value>
            </GridDivisions>
            <Toggle Key="perspective">
              <Value>false</Value>
              <Variant>Perspective</Variant>
            </Toggle>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>true</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>false</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
        </Plane>
        <CrossMark id="25dda1e6-f474-4c51-a1bb-d17da0d3588a" name="Marker 1">
          <CenterPoint>1330.364;405</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>1281;283</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="370.36" UserXInvariant="370.36" UserY="135.00" UserYInvariant="135.00" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="9686f0e3-c2ae-4e61-b634-2bf49e29b16c" name="Marker 2">
          <CenterPoint>1266.545;336.2727</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>1217;214</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="306.55" UserXInvariant="306.55" UserY="203.73" UserYInvariant="203.73" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="e22268ef-0348-4aba-bacd-6830227fe877" name="Marker 3">
          <CenterPoint>1553.727;753.5455</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>1504;631</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="593.73" UserXInvariant="593.73" UserY="-213.55" UserYInvariant="-213.55" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="26bcf39d-75ea-4353-b26b-47bb86549a16" name="Marker 4">
          <CenterPoint>1445.727;758.4545</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>1396;636</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="485.73" UserXInvariant="485.73" UserY="-218.45" UserYInvariant="-218.45" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="d45e5715-09d0-4f98-b533-71f30fb23fb6" name="Marker 5">
          <CenterPoint>1620;844.3636</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>1571;722</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="660.00" UserXInvariant="660.00" UserY="-304.36" UserYInvariant="-304.36" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="96fbec04-de71-4a98-a55b-9f4f5d62b4bf" name="Marker 6">
          <CenterPoint>682.3636;635.7273</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>633;513</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="-277.64" UserXInvariant="-277.64" UserY="-95.73" UserYInvariant="-95.73" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="59209987-854f-4d6a-95e4-8d4a35bc1b70" name="Marker 7">
          <CenterPoint>684.8182;687.2727</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>635;565</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="-275.18" UserXInvariant="-275.18" UserY="-147.27" UserYInvariant="-147.27" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="47483b27-2d37-4448-bb39-3c43efa6d29b" name="Marker 8">
          <CenterPoint>552.2727;392.7273</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>503;270</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="-407.73" UserXInvariant="-407.73" UserY="147.27" UserYInvariant="147.27" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="02448ccf-5298-4244-b4ab-05c41f2df372" name="Marker 9">
          <CenterPoint>390.2727;481.0909</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>341;359</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="-569.73" UserXInvariant="-569.73" UserY="58.91" UserYInvariant="58.91" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
        <CrossMark id="fb18c303-3e63-4c55-9000-80dc90bc65ba" name="Marker 10">
          <CenterPoint>260.1818;142.3636</CenterPoint>
          <ExtraData>None</ExtraData>
          <MeasureLabel>
            <SpacePosition>211;20</SpacePosition>
            <TimePosition>0</TimePosition>
          </MeasureLabel>
          <DrawingStyle>
            <Color Key="back color">
              <Value>255;0;0;0</Value>
            </Color>
          </DrawingStyle>
          <InfosFading>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Frames>20</Frames>
            <AlwaysVisible>false</AlwaysVisible>
            <UseDefault>true</UseDefault>
          </InfosFading>
          <Coordinates UserX="-699.82" UserXInvariant="-699.82" UserY="397.64" UserYInvariant="397.64" UserUnitLength="px" />
        </CrossMark>
      </Drawings>
    </Keyframe>
  </Keyframes>
  <CoordinateSystem id="48cc63a9-8e28-4c15-bef5-6404756a50b1" name="Coordinate System 1">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <DrawingStyle>
      <Color Key="line color">
        <Value>255;255;0;0</Value>
      </Color>
    </DrawingStyle>
  </CoordinateSystem>
  <Trackability />
</KinoveaVideoAnalysis>
```

I have written the below code for it:

```
X = []
Y = []
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = list('XY'))

path = "C:/Users/HP 15-da0327tu/Desktop/JupyterNotebooks/Pool Analysis XML Duplicate/XML ex-KVA"
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xml")):
    with open(filename) as currentfile:
        X = []
        Y = []
        parser = et.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
        tree = et.parse(currentfile, parser=parser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        print(et.tostring(root))
        for kfs in root.iter('Keyframes'):
            root1 = et.Element('root')
            root1 = kfs
            for kf in root1.iter('Keyframe'):
                root2 = et.Element('root')
                root2 = kf
                for cm in root2.iter('CrossMark'):
                    root3 = et.Element('root')
                    root3 = cm
                    for coord in root3.iter('Coordinates'):
                        X.append(coord.attrib['UserX'])
                        Y.append(coord.attrib['UserY'])
        df.append([X, Y])
```

Moreover, the simplified code works with a single file. This code...

```
Xdemo = []
Ydemo = []

onetree = et.parse("XML ex-KVA\World Cup of Pool 2018 SF Austria vs China B 11.xml")
root = onetree.getroot()
for kfs in root.iter('Keyframes'):
    root1 = et.Element('root')
    root1 = kfs
    for kf in root1.iter('Keyframe'):
        root2 = et.Element('root')
        root2 = kf
        for cm in root2.iter('CrossMark'):
            root3 = et.Element('root')
            root3 = cm
            for coord in root3.iter('Coordinates'):
                Xdemo.append(coord.attrib['UserX'])
                Ydemo.append(coord.attrib['UserY'])

dfDemo = pd.DataFrame({'X':Xdemo, 'Y':Ydemo})

print(dfDemo)
```

...gives this:

```
         X        Y
0  -243.27    93.27
1  -302.18    27.00
2  -535.36    71.18
3  -528.00   157.09
4  -429.82   196.36
5  -402.82   324.00
6    29.18   120.27
7   247.64   198.82
8   328.64  -100.64
9  -702.27  -328.91
```

I am still a novice with Python, so if there are any other problems with my code, or better solutions that can be given in order to be able to run through the DataFrame (10 coordinates at a time) and give the results, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Clearly you should update your code to identify the errant XML file and take a look at it specifically.

Comment: I do not get your point. All the XML files, nearly a thousand of them, are structured in the same way, and there are no non-XML files in the folder. So I cannot see any problem in the way the files are structured.

Comment: And yet you have a problem.  (We can't trust your assessment that all of your files are the same when you're also telling us that one of them is failing.)   For our sake as well as yours, reduce the search space of your problem to the smallest data in and code that exhibits the problem.   Create and post a  [mcve] -- note ***minimum*** and ***reproducible*** (on our end).

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to add `encoding = "utf-8"` to the `with open` statement, as in `with open(filename, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as currentfile:`. Only then is the parser able to work.